# What did Voldemort look like before dying at the Potters' house?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

Did Voldemort look the same as he does in books 6 and 7 after killing Lily and James? I would think he would look more human, but maybe the dark magic changed his appearance after he left Hogwarts.

Comment: he rezes in book 4, looking like he died

Comment: I'm pretty sure the strange look with no nose and stuff comes from the regeneration, not the dark magic.

Answer (score 20):

When Voldemort regains his body he looks like this

> Voldemort looked away from Harry, and began examining his
>   own body. His hands were like large, pale spiders; his long
>   white fingers caressed his own chest, his arms, his face; the red
>   eyes, whose pupils were slits, like a cat’s, gleamed still more
>   brightly through the darkness. He held up his hands, and
>   flexed the fingers, his expression rapt and exultant.

This is all due to the transfiguration he did on his body **Before** going to the Potters.

Years prior to the attack,

> His features were not those Harry had seen emerge
>   from the great stone cauldron almost two years before; they
>   were not as snakelike, the eyes were not yet scarlet, the face
>   not yet masklike, and yet he was no longer handsome Tom
>   Riddle. It was as though his features had been burned and
>   blurred; they were waxy and oddly distorted, and the whites
>   of the eyes now had a permanently bloody look, though the
>   pupils were not yet the slits that Harry knew they would
>   become. He was wearing a long black cloak and his face was
>   as pale as the snow glistening on his shoulders.

Voldemort already looked "almost" like in the years preceding the start of the first Wizarding war in which the potters died. This shows he has been actively modifying his appearance for years. Additionally [When did Tom Riddle get his new face?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14866/when-did-tom-riddle-get-his-new-face)

Comment: Good quotations, but “actively modifying his appearance” (while technically not wrong) makes it sound like regular appointments with his plastical surgeon, when his changed looks were actually a side effect of his dark activities.

Answer (score 6):

## He looked like he did when ‘reborn’.

The Dark Lord looked the same when he killed the Potters as he did when he was restored to a body. When Harry sees him, Harry sees ‘the face that had haunted his nightmares for three years’.

> “The thin man stepped out of the cauldron, staring at Harry … and Harry stared back into the face that had haunted his nightmares for three years.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 32 (Flesh, Blood and Bone)*</sup></sub>

The nightmares Harry refers to are likely the ones he has of the night his parents died, meaning the Dark Lord looked the same then.

Answer (score 2):

He had a gradual transition from the handsome T.M. Riddle to Voldemort, looking less human and more snakelike with each Horcrux he created. If you're talking about the time just before accidentally making Harry into a Horcrux (when he perished at the Potter's house), he would have looked the same as he did when Harry saw him resurrected. People at the MoM who saw Voldemort in the battle at the end of OotP used their seeing him as what jolted them to the realization that Voldemort was indeed back, which would not have happened if he looked different before Halloween, 1981.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly before killing Lily and James, his appearance must have been the same as he did when he visited Hogwarts to ask Dumbledore for a DADA professorship. Because when he visited Hogwarts, he made only five Horcruxes: the diary, the ring, the goblet, the rocket, and the daidem. The sixth Horcrux was Harry Potter (when he killed Lily and James and cast a murder curse on Harry), and the seventh was Nagini (one year before his resurrection). Voldemort's appearance in the Sorcerer's Stone is probably what it looked like before Nagini was turned into a Horcrux, and the appearance when he was resurrected in Volume 4 is what he looked like after completing all the Horcruxes.

Comment: Do you have anything to back this up? "must have been", "probably", smacks of opnion.

Answer (score -1):

I think he looked more like how he did in the philosopher's stone when he was in the back of Quirrells head? He was human but was closer to how he looked. He had a nose, the red eyes, pale skin and the human features but the rebirth body took his snake like appearance to the extreme.

Comment: This seems to be solely your opinion, do you have any evidence that you could [edit] in that this is indeed true or anything to back this up with?