# Why does Voldemort become more snakelike?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

So we know that Voldemort's appearance became more snakelike as he made more horcruxes and dove deeper into dark magic, but why did he become more like a *snake* and not more like any other animal or creature?

---

Relate: [How did Voldemort's face get disfigured?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17431/how-did-voldemorts-face-get-disfigured)

Comment: It's his favourite animal? The Slytherin connection? His Parselmouth abilities? To mark him out as the bad guy? All viable options, none of them proveable.

Comment: @TheDarkLord Well, *you* should know! ;)

Comment: It is possible that it was a conscious choice.  There is no evidence for or against this possibility, but he clearly has an affinity with snakes (being related to Slytherin, speaking parseltongue, choosing a snake for a horcrux, etc)

Comment: Are you entirely sure that his face became 'like a snake' rather than simply being deformed? And that deformity making him look 'snakelike'?

Comment: I'm not satisfied that this question is different enough to re-open. Most of the answers in the linked question make mention of his snake-like tendencies anyway.

Comment: Also related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/14868/21267