# What does Lord Voldemort's lower body look like?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

After Lord Voldemort is resurrected in HP:GoF, he is always seen wearing a long black cloak which covers him below the neck, except for his hands. Since Lord Voldemort is Slytherin-based he is more influenced by snakes. Even his looks are snakelike. Slit-like nose and face and so on. Also, most of times when travelling over distance, he is shown to fly in cloth like orb form which all Death Eaters do.

What I want to know is that, does Lord Voldemort have legs or a snakelike body using which he slithers around?

Comment: "is Slytherin based"...  He's made of Slytherinium?

Comment: Related http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17431/what-really-happened-to-the-nose-of-voldemort

Comment: I thought you were going after something different when I read “lower body”...

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez Well, Voldemort's "lower body" *is* snakelike.

Comment: This question is being asked for a fanfic, isn't it.

Comment: Fred and George say something about him having feet on their radio show I think.

Comment: @Bellerophon I think Fred and George are not authorities on this topic, because they've not met the Dark Lord in person before the Battle of Hogwarts.

Comment: @b_jonas Their radio show is made by people who fought Voldemort in the first war though so they might know some stuff. Also Harry probably told them a bit about Voldemort.

Comment: Doesn't he also touch dead Cedric's face with his feet early on in the graveyard scene? I could be imagining that...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The best image I can find of Voldemort's full body is actually of an officially licensed sculpture from Gentle Giant. As you can see, Voldemort has feet. Thus, he does not have a snake body.

(Or he has the world's strangest snake body ever.)

[image]

You can also see feet in this screencap of Voldemort after his battle with Harry.

[image]

Comment: And comfy, sensible shoes/loafers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your last image is not actually from the movie. Must be a BTS thing. Voldemort disintegrates into flakes that float away and so Harry never walks up to his body. :)

Comment: @RedCaio in the books he just dies and his body lies on the ground (which is far better than the snowflakes but arguably less impressive) so they might have shot two possible versions of the scene and chose the latest one in editing..

Comment: you can also see his legs when he kills all who bring the news that hufflepuff cup was stolen.

Answer (score 21):

Oh I mean, he certainly has feet, for example,

> He paced the room, kicking aside the goblin's corpse as he passed, and the pictures blurred and burned in his boiling brain: the lake, the shack, and Hogwarts -
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - p.444 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 27, *The Final Hiding Place*

And

> 'SILENCE!' cried Voldemort, and there was a bang and a flash of bright light, and silence was forced upon them all. 'It is over! Set him down, Hagrid, at my feet, where he belongs!'
>
> Harry felt himself lowered on to the grass.
>
> 'You see?' said Voldemort, and Harry felt him striding backwards and forwards right beside the place where he lay.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - p.585 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 36, *The Flaw in the Plan*

He still had a human form. He'd just been somewhat mutilated by his Horcrux making and general heinous acts.

> '...Lord Voldemort had seemed to grow less human with the passing years, and the transformation he had undergone seemed to me to be only explicable if his soul was mutilated beyond the realms of what we might call usual evil ...'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* - p.469 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 23, *Horcruxes*

Also, just to movie-canon this answer up a bit, here's a still from *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows - Part 2* showing Voldemort's actual feet as he walks among the Gringotts goblins that he slew on learning that Harry was hunting Horcruxes.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

## The Dark Lord’s outline was of a man, he had legs, and walked.

When the Dark Lord rises up from the cauldron, before he has his robes put on, Harry sees him having the outline of a man. That would mean the basic shape of the Dark Lord wasn’t visibly different from the average man. Presumably this would include having legs.

> “But then, through the mist in front of him, he saw, with an icy surge of terror, the dark outline of a man, tall and skeletally thin, rising slowly from inside the cauldron.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 32 (Flesh, Blood and Bone)*</sup></sub>

The Dark Lord then *steps* out of the cauldron, which would be impossible with a snakelike lack of legs or feet that he could use to step out of it with. He’d need legs to step out.

> “The thin man stepped out of the cauldron, staring at Harry … and Harry stared back into the face that had haunted his nightmares for three years.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 32 (Flesh, Blood and Bone)*</sup></sub>

He’s later described as walking, which is again impossible without legs or feet to walk with.

> “Voldemort laughed again. Up and down he paced, looking all around him as he walked, and the snake continued to circle in the grass.”  
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 32 (Flesh, Blood and Bone)*</sup></sub>

Therefore, though his facial appearance was snakelike, he still had legs and feet.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to say he's got legs, I'm sure throughout the books he's described as walking at some point. If he had a snakelike body I think J.K would have said so. Also remember he was a least born a human I don't think he could have altered his body that much.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth mentioning that, in *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child*, it is revealed that Voldemort

> has a (fully human) daughter.

The fact that she is fully human and shows no signs of being part-snake indicates that Voldemort, even though he does have a snake-*like* eyes and nose, is fully human himself. He has a damaged soul, yes, but still his is an otherwise normal human body.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the other answers providing citations that indicate that Voldemort has feet and walks, in *Deathly Hallows* when Harry has an unprecedented view of Voldemort's movements Voldemort is frequently described as "gliding". One time he is actually explicitly described as "slithering". Thus, even if Voldemort does not actually have the physical body of a snake, his movements definitely evoke a snakelike body (and that is presumably the image the author wished to conjure).

- > He was gliding along a twilit street.
- > Abandoning the attempt to close the door, she began to back away down
  >   the dark hall, and Harry followed, gliding toward her, and his
  >   long-fingered hand had drawn his wand.
- > *And he was gliding along, that sense of purpose and power and
  >   rightness in him that he always knew on these occasions.*
- > Voldemort's thoughts had suddenly become razor-sharp again; he was
  >   gliding toward the gigantic building with a sense of calmly euphoric
  >   purpose....
- > *– He was gliding around the high walls of the black fortress –*
- > The sun was barely visible over the horizon as he glided alongside
  >   Snape, up through the grounds toward the lake.
- > *And he made less noise than the dead leaves slithering along the
  >   pavement as he drew level with the dark hedge, and stared over it....*

On the other hand, having legs is specifically given by Fred Weasley as the characteristic that *distinguishes* Voldemort from a snake:

> "Agreed," said Fred. "So, people, let's try and calm down a bit.
>   Things are bad enough without inventing stuff as well.For instance,
>   this new idea that You-Know-Who can kill with a single glance from his
>   eyes. That's a *basilisk*, listeners. One simple test: Check whether
>   the thing that's glaring at you has got legs. If it has, it's safe to
>   look into it's eyes, although if it really is You-Know-Who, that's
>   still likely to be the last thing you ever do."

Comment: Couldn't the gliding part just be Voldemort "flying" low, giving this gliding feel to impress the populace?

Comment: @Jenayah It could in theory, but in most of the contexts it seems clear that he is traveling on the ground.