# was Voldemort's body snakelike before his Resurrection?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

I am confused, did Voldemort look like a snake before he died the first time, or like Tom Riddle? the people at the ministry in OotP recognized him, so does that mean he was all disfigured then, or was that the result of the potion that resurrected him? even though this is marked as duplicate, i still want an answer, and the other questions don't fully answer this question (for what i want from it)

Comment: In what way does [slytherincess' answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/17434/5184) not answer the question? She explains that he is disfigured prior to his death.